# Submitting Documentation edit fails, but error message is missing

Tags: bug, documentation

After using button "submit for review" I get a red field over the "brief explanation" textfield without any error hint and the action has not succeeded.

This happens only with all examples of a special topic ([C++ Language] Keywords); other topic editing happens well.

[image]

Comment: It is *probably* trying to tell you that there are already too many examples in that topic, and you cannot add any more. However, if the error message isn't showing up, that is most definitely a bug.

Comment: @Cody Gray: No, I try to edit an existing example. Yes, there is no message text.