# Problem saving edits, results in inability to view topic

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-topics

Similar to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334207/submitting-documentation-edit-fails-but-error-message-is-missing), I tried creating some "Remarks" in a topic and got an empty red box as an error message when I tried to submit the change. Watching the requests in the browser inspector, I could see an empty 500 error coming back from the save attempt. So I gave up and [saved the draft](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/powershell/drafts/96319).

Now, trying to go back to [view that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/powershell/7208/conditional-logic), or the draft, I can't even look at it (possibly similar to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328975/cant-open-any-draft-always-return-500-error)) as I get the ["Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error page](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/powershell/7208/conditional-logic).

I had this problem a few months ago, commented on a few questions here, and moved on, hoping it would be fixed in time. But it's obviously still a problem and it seems like there are quite [a](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329675/cant-view-topic) [few](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329030/cant-open-documentation-topic-after-move-examples-request) [unanswered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337159/discarded-attempt-to-move-an-example-now-results-in-an-error) [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330192/documentation-moved-an-example-the-topic-is-now-bugged-unavailable) in a similar vein.

Comment: I can see the topic just fine, so it just affects you on this particular topic.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case for most of these reports.

Comment: Give it a try now, think it was a dodge orphan record from a bit ago that got cleaned up.

Comment: @KevinMontrose It does seem to be working. Do you mean an orphan record on my account? The edit I tried to make was in a topic and tag that I've never edited before.

Comment: Orphaned on your account but a different topic, was breaking rendering of a component in the sidebar of the editor.  Will do a more proper write up when I get back at my desk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was caused by an orphaned example draft record, which I've now removed.

In a somewhat round-about way, this made it so an element in the sidebar wouldn't render.  Because the sidebar is rendered via ajax when you *first* edit, that page worked - but subsequent visits try to render the sidebar server side (for a snappier UX), which exploded.

The root cause of the orphaned record has been fixed for a bit, but in the cleanup this one got missed.